# In SQL Server 2008, is it possible to have aliased or named connections in the 'Connect to Server' dialog?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I work in an environment where I have to connect to SQL Server databases hosted on different servers with many different application logins.  I might have ten different application logins for a single database instance.

I find it incredibly difficult finding the stored connection parameters in SQL Server's "Connect to Server" prompt.  Is it possible to name my various connections with nice aliases (like in SQL Developer or Toad for Oracle) to help me keep track of what connection goes where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

That is, you have "App1", "App2" etc to mask the actual DB instance. Then you "train" SSMS to remember logins for that alias.

You set up client-only aliases using SQL Server "SQL Server Configuration Manager", then "SQL Server Native Client Configuration", "Aliases". [As per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445.aspx)